# gdal2tiles in FWTools Shell

Tags: gdal2tiles

I install FWTools in Windows7 and run FWTools Shell,after type gdal2tiles,but give error 'no module named osgeo' . [image]

also i installed OSGEO4W ,but another error to happen

[image]

Comment: Your 2nd screenshot shows that you are not using "OSGEO4W Shell". Without it,  some environment variables for GDAL are not loaded hence your second issue http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/_images/54.png. To open it, see https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tapir79/pics/master/plg6.png

Answer (score 4):

It's simply because FWTools is so old that it does not use `osgeo` Python namespace as illustrated at the bottom of [the GDAL Python section about import](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython#imports)

You should install GDAL via [OSGEO4W](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/) or [GIS internal](http://www.gisinternals.com/release.php) instead of using the outdated FWTools

Comment: Did you try manually Python by doing `python`, then in the command `import osgeo`? You need to install gdal python executables with the OSGEOW4 and also need to run the command not via the classic DOS command but through the "OSGEO4W Shell"

Comment: MR Thomas,OSGeo4W also give gdal error.

Comment: And how did you proceed to install GDAL in OSGEO4W? How did you run gdal2tiles? Can't help without more info

Comment: I use osgeo4w-setup-x86.exe for install osgeo4w,also checked gdal and gdal_python,run OSGeo4W Shell and write gdal2tiles,but error ImportError: No module named gdal

Comment: Did you go in "Advanced install" and installed the "gdal-python"? If not, run again the osgeo4w-setup-x86.exe and do it

Comment: yes,i go in Advanced install and installed gdal-python

Comment: I don't see anymore as I have no issue doing the same on my machine

Comment: is it possible i use files you(upload zip files and send link download)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34241/discussion-between-thomasg77-and-mhkyazd).